# How to run a built .NET 7.0 console app in Azure DevOps build pipline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a build pipeline which builds a few C# projects successfully. One of the projects is a console app that does some certain things and we'd like to have it run in the pipeline using the following yaml code snippet:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run my.NET Console application
  continueOnError: false
  inputs:
    command: 'run'
    projects: '**/MyConsoleApp.csproj'
    arguments: '''--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'''
```

The build pipeline's yaml file has the following very first step to ensure the dotnet sdk is installed beforehand on the build agent:

```yaml
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 7.0.400
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

Unfortunately running it results in the following failure:

> ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 134

> ##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
> Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

What is the solution for this problem to be able to run the console app in the Linux build agent?

Comment: This error you get installing dotnet or running app? If running app, are you sure it is  targeting net7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to fix the issue:

1. Enable **`InvariantGlobalization`** on your C# console app. Add the property below in the **`.csproj`** file of your console app.

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
      <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Install **`ICU`** library on your Linux agent.

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
   ```

Comment: This solution did not work. Can you please explain why we need ICU and why the invariant globalization = true will fix the issue?

Comment: @Arash, Referenced this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6172

Comment: @Brian Ran-MSFT But we are talking about two different things. Your answer is not consistent with my question.